# Prevent entity deletion if related entity exists

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I'm working with JPA 2 + Hibernate 4 and I'm implementing some CRUD operations on model entities.

Now I need to prevent a certain entity (`EntityB`) to be deleted when a related entity (`EntityA`) exists in database:

```
@Entity
public class EntityA {
    @Id
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "entityA", optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private EntityB entityB;

    //...
}

@Entity
public class EntityB {
    @Id
    private int id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private EntityA entityA;

    //...
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this using relationship options or should I check `EntityA` existence in my dao/repository before removing `EntityB`?

**NOTE** I need this also for `@ManyToOne` relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent that in your code, than simply do not delete that entity (by checking that manually). There is no possibility to do that with annotations.

On the other side, this sounds to me rather like a need for a DB constraint. If those entities are already related, then simply add a foreign key constraint (if none is existent). If not, than think of adding one.

PS: if you already have a relationship, check the CascadeType.REMOVE setting.

Comment: Agree about DB constraint. +1. Please CascadeType.REMOVE remove this line, it does not fit, because it just removes ref to related fields...

Comment: yes, I think setting a DB constraint is the right approach for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can solve this with annotations. You should manally check related-entity existence before.